System.StackOverflowException occurring only in Debug mode, not in Release mode despite absence of recursive calls
I'm encountering a perplexing issue in my application where a System.StackOverflowException is being thrown, but only in Debug mode and not in Release mode. The error occurs within a specific function, despite the absence of any recursive calls or apparent infinite loops within that function.
Here's a brief summary of the problem:

The exception occurs at the first statement of a particular function.

There are no recursive calls within this function.

The issue is only reproducible in Debug mode, while in Release mode the code executes without any errors.


I've already checked for circular dependencies, infinite loops, and reviewed compiler warnings, but haven't found any obvious reasons for the discrepancy between Debug and Release modes.
I'm seeking insights into potential causes for this behavior and suggestions for further troubleshooting steps. Could this be related to differences in optimizations between Debug and Release modes, or are there other factors I should consider?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
Error generate code block
 AutoHoldSpecialPunch = dbEntntiy.Settings.Where(x => x.SettingName == "Special Punch Auto MFG Hold")
    .Select(a => a.SettingValue).FirstOrDefault();

SQL Script of table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Setting](
    [SettingId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SettingName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [SettingValue] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [IsNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Setting] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SettingId] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Setting] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Table_1_is_number]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsNumber]
GO

In my attempt to address the System.StackOverflowException issue, I've tried several troubleshooting steps:

Reviewed the code of the function where the exception occurs.

Ensured there are no recursive calls or infinite loops within the function.

Checked for circular dependencies or any other potential causes of excessive stack usage.

Investigated differences in optimizations between Debug and Release modes.

Examined compiler warnings and static code analysis results.

Used the debugger to step through the code and identify the exact location of the exception.

Reviewed documentation for any known issues related to stack usage or optimization settings.


I was expecting to identify the root cause of the System.StackOverflowException and resolve it, especially considering the absence of recursive calls or apparent causes for excessive stack usage within the function. However, despite these efforts, the issue persists, and I'm still unsure why it occurs only in Debug mode and not in Release mode.

It would be ideal if you could give us the steps to reproduce. It working those out you'll have an awesome chance to figure out your own issue.

The sample code seem too simple to be the root cause. Did you check the call stack when hitting the exception? Might be a reentrancy problem. Maybe setting AutoHoldSpecialPunch (very) indirectly involve reaching that same piece of code? It might involve several method calls before repeating the call chain. If UI is involved, it can be some event triggering an update, that in turn triggers the event. Another scenario could be something similar but when setting a value of a property.

Just a guess but maybe look into the created SQL. I have the feeling it could be beneficial to rearrange the order of filter, limit and projection. I.e. first filter and FirstOrDefault (which can be done in one call) and then project to SettingValue. Then compare resulting sql queries and their execution plans.
